# WiaClass could not be found

Tags: c#, wia

I'm trying to start work with WIA but my problem with each turtorial starts at begin.

```
WiaClass wiaManager = null;
```

I get error like "Type or namespace name 'WiaClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I use Visual Studio Community 2015 on Windows10. Of course i have line

```
using WIA;
```

and added references.

Where I should search for problem?

Comment: Is the namespace used definitely correct? Does it possibly need to be `using WIALib` instead?

Comment: using WIALib give me an error like "WIALib namespace could not be found"

Comment: There is no "WiaClass" type in that type library.  Impossible to guess what you meant from just a single line of bad code.  Use Object Browser to look in the interop library.

Comment: It sounds like you need to find a better tutorial - perhaps you should exclude anything which references `WiaClass`, for starters: https://www.google.com/search?q=wia+c%23+-wiaclass